# как получить размер диагональ экрана в сантиметрах?

Tags: java, android

я здесь нашел пример как получить диагональ экрана. и он не правильно считает. даже если я перевел в сантиметры.

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

double x = Math.pow(dm.widthPixels / dm.xdpi, 2);
double y = Math.pow(dm.heightPixels / dm.ydpi, 2);
double screenInches = Math.sqrt(x + y);
screenInches *= 2.54;
```

у меня планшет, а он показывает диагональ как будто экран в диагонали около 12 сантиметров. а экран у меня вроде больше 20 сантиметров. как правильно считать?
я попробовал поделить на другое значение.

```
double x = Math.pow(dm.widthPixels / dm.densityDpi, 2);
double y = Math.pow(dm.heightPixels / dm.densityDpi, 2);
```

значение уже блин, получается 21 сантиметр, но у меня экран где-то 26 сантиметров.

Comment: Мне кажется эта строка: 
'double screenInches = Math.sqrt(x + y);'
должна выглядеть так
'double screenInches = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);'

Comment: @ВиталийПерятин да не, всё правильно. где то прочитал что планшеты будут около 11, а телефоны около 4.

Comment: Дело в том, что суть этого кода заключается в нахождении ширины экрана, потом нахождении высоты экрана, а потом получения диагонали через стандартную формулу Пифагора. У Вас неверно написана формула Пифагора

Comment: @ВиталийПерятин все верно! Оформите ваш комментарий как ответ

Answer (score 1):

Cуть этого кода заключается в нахождении ширины экрана, потом нахождении высоты экрана, а потом получения диагонали через стандартную формулу Пифагора. У Вас неверно написана формула Пифагора

Эта строка:

```
double screenInches = Math.sqrt(x + y);
```

должна выглядеть так:

```
double screenInches = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
```

Comment: А почему ответ без правильного кода?

Comment: у вас не правильный ответ.

Comment: @xverizex поясните, что не так?

Comment: вот эта функция когда поделит, как раз вычислит квадрат потом x и y. `Math.pow(dm.widthPixels / dm.xdpi, 2);` `pow 2` это возвести в квадрат. у вас лишний раз в квадрат возводиться.